# How to split characters of string equally between buttons?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, unity-game-engine, split

I have an array of string elements of various words. I need the characters of each word be split equally into the text component of 3 buttons. For example, the array could hold the elements `"maybe", "his", "car"`. In each game one of these words will be pulled from the array and its characters divided into the 3 buttons. For example, button 1 will have `"ma"`, button 2 will have `"yb"` and button 3 `"e"` (for the word maybe). I then hide the text element of one button for the user to drag and drop the correct missing letter(s) into the space. The purpose of the game is to help children learn to spell. Does anyone know how I could go about dividing the characters equally into the 3 buttons?

Comment: What's your criteria for dividing? What if the word is less than 3 characters long? If it's longer than 3, how do you want to divide it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a function that would split the word into the amount of segments you want. You can then iterate over that list to set each segment to a button.Text.

```
public List<string> SplitInSegments(string word, int segments)
{
    int wordLength = word.Length;

    // The remainder tells us how many segments will get an extra letter
    int remainder = wordLength % segments;

    // The base length of a segment
    // This is a floor division, because we're dividing ints.
    // So 5 / 3 = 1
    int segmentLength = wordLength / segments;

    var result = new List<string>();
    int startIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < segments; i++)
    {
        // This segment may get an extra letter, if its index is smaller then the remainder
        int currentSegmentLength = segmentLength + (i < remainder ? 1 : 0);

        string currentSegment = word.Substring(startIndex, currentSegmentLength);

        // Set the startindex for the next segment.
        startIndex += currentSegmentLength;

        result.Add(currentSegment);
    }

    return result;
}
```

usage:

```
// returns ["ma", "yb", "e"]
var segments = SplitInSegments("maybe", 3);
```

## Edit

I like the fact that this is for teaching children. So here comes.
Regarding your question on splitting the string based on specific letter sequences: After you've split the string using regex, you will have an array of strings. Then determine the amount of items in the splitted string and concatenate or split further based on the number of segments:

```
// sequences to split on first
static readonly string[] splitSequences = {
    "el",
    "ol",
    "bo"
};

static readonly string regexDelimiters = string.Join('|', splitSequences.Select(s => "(" + s + ")"));

// Method to split on sequences
public static List<string> SplitOnSequences(string word)
{
    return Regex.Split(word, regexDelimiters).Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToList();
}

public static List<string> SplitInSegments(string word, int segments)
{
    int wordLength = word.Length;

    // The remainder tells us how many segments will get an extra letter
    int remainder = wordLength % segments;

    // The base length of a segment
    // This is a floor division, because we're dividing ints.
    // So 5 / 3 = 1
    int segmentLength = wordLength / segments;

    var result = new List<string>();
    int startIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < segments; i++)
    {
        // This segment may get an extra letter, if its index is smaller then the remainder
        int currentSegmentLength = segmentLength + (i < remainder ? 1 : 0);

        string currentSegment = word.Substring(startIndex, currentSegmentLength);

        // Set the startindex for the next segment.
        startIndex += currentSegmentLength;

        result.Add(currentSegment);
    }

    return result;
}

// Splitword will now always return 3 segments
public static List<string> SplitWord(string word)
{
    if (word == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(word));
    }

    if (word.Length < 3)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Word must be at least 3 characters long", nameof(word));
    }

    var splitted = SplitOnSequences(word);

    var result = new List<string>();
    if (splitted.Count == 1)
    {
        // If the result is not splitted, just split it evenly.
        result = SplitInSegments(word, 3);
    }
    else if (splitted.Count == 2)
    {
        // If we've got 2 segments, split the shortest segment again.
        if (splitted[1].Length > splitted[0].Length
            && !splitSequences.Contains(splitted[1]))
        {
            result.Add(splitted[0]);
            result.AddRange(SplitInSegments(splitted[1], 2));
        }
        else
        {
            result.AddRange(SplitInSegments(splitted[0], 2));
            result.Add(splitted[1]);
        }
    }
    else // splitted.Count >= 3
    { 
        // 3 segments is good.
        result = splitted;

        // More than 3 segments, combine some together.
        while (result.Count > 3)
        {
            // Find the shortest combination of two segments
            int shortestComboCount = int.MaxValue;
            int shortestComboIndex = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < result.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                int currentComboCount = result[i].Length + result[i + 1].Length;
                if (currentComboCount < shortestComboCount)
                {
                    shortestComboCount = currentComboCount;
                    shortestComboIndex = i;
                }
            }

            // Combine the shortest segments and replace in the result.
            string combo = result[shortestComboIndex] + result[shortestComboIndex + 1];
            result.RemoveAt(shortestComboIndex + 1);
            result[shortestComboIndex] = combo;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Now when you call the code:

```
// always returns three segments.
var splitted = SplitWord(word);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I've just tried your code and it worked a treat! Thank you. I've also just thought of something.... I'll be splitting the word using a Regex.Split() first.... i.e I'm splitting the word if it contains a particular 2 adjoining letters. Do you know how I could pass an array of strings to the function?

Comment: Thank you @JessedeWit. I'm a bit confused to how calling the function for each iteration of the array would work :/ if the first element of the array contained 2 characters, the function would try and split it into 3 segments?

Comment: @JessedeWit Or could I do the split based on an array of strings e.g. 'el', 'ol' etc?

Comment: @JessedeWit I do apologise that it seems I'm quite indecisive to what I actually want! I have thought it through but find it difficult to put it into words :( basically what I'd like is to use the function you provided but splitting the input string based on specific characters e.g `el`. So for example, if a word contains the letters `el` (there will only be one occurrence of it in the word) I'd like the `el` part of the word to be in its own button text. I can then hide the text within the button so that the user can guess it.

Comment: @JessedeWit Thank you for that suggestion. The only issue is, I have dozens and dozens of input strings to feed into the game.... will probably take me too long to split them up manually. Do you think there would be a way programmatically to achieve it?

Comment: @JessedeWit Thank you so much for all the help you've given, I really appreciate your time in helping me. Can I just ask one last question? How does the edited code you added fit in with ensuring the strings get spread between 3 buttons? Sorry for a daft question if it's quite obvious! You've been very patient fair play!

Comment: @JessedeWit Ah right ok I see... the annoying thing is I have to stick with 3 buttons in the game :( each button has been specially designed by an artist :S typical!

Comment: @Lloyd SplitWord now always returns three segments ;-)

Comment: @Lloyd note that I'd appreciate it if you'd mark this as the answer.

Comment: Thank you so so much, it worked a charm! I've just marked your answer as the solution! Thanks again!

Comment: @JessedeWit I am so sorry for bugging you again! Just a question though! The game spec has changed and instead of passing an array of delimiters, the delimiter will be pre-defined for each word. How would you just pass a single variable to your method? I've tried doing so but run into problems with static constraints :/ I'm getting the variable from an array of class elements for each word I've made i.e. `classArray[indexOfTheClassArray].delimiter`. Sorry for bugging you again. I'd totally understand if you've had enough helping me!

Comment: Let us [continue our discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197789/how-to-split-characters-of-string-equally-between-buttons)

Comment: @JessedeWit Thank you so much, I've just sent you some messages through the chat :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach.

First make sure that the word can be divided by the desired segments (add a dummy space if necessary) , then use a Linq statement to get your parts and when adding the result trim away the dummy characters.

```
public static string[] SplitInSegments(string word, int segments)
{
    while(word.Length %  segments != 0) { word+=" ";}
    var result = new List<string>();
    for(int x=0; x < word.Count(); x += word.Length / segments)
    result.Add((new string(word.Skip(x).Take(word.Length / segments).ToArray()).Trim()));
    return result.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: If you'd split "maybe" in 4 segments, your code outputs ["ma", "yb", "e", ""], I'd expect ["ma", "y", "b", "e"] (although I know that's not the question, the function signature suggests it's possible)

Answer (score -2):

You can split your string into a list and generate buttons based on your list. The logic for splitting the word into a string list would be something similar to this:

string test = "maybe";
        List list = new List();

```
    int i = 0, len = 2;
    while(i <= test.Length)
    {
        int lastIndex = test.Length - 1;
        list.Add(test.Substring(i, i + len > lastIndex? (i + len) - test.Length : len));
        i += len;       
    }
```

HTH

Comment: This generates and exception if word length is 8, splits into more than 3 if the length is 9. Please test your solutions before posting.

Comment: `A downvote for this is a bit harsh`, TBH I don't think it is as you mentioned; `the OP is not even providing what they have tried`, why would you post an answer in the first place to a post when there are *no* details. OP asked for help, but didn't provide details for us to help, but we have a solution here that also doesn't work, what are your thoughts?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I do think its a bit harsh considering the OP did not provide ANY code. The intention was to point into a direction so that they can DO the ACTUAL work based off of the example/idea. We're not here to provide a coding service after all!!! Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Sach SO is not a coding service, but we're here to help. Thanks for the down talk!

Comment: Incomplete and erroneous code isn't help. If you wanted to point the OP in right direction you could actually guide him/her. You have zero explanations to your code, and the code has errors.

Comment: Works with the scenario provided. They can tweak the code from there, once they grasp the idea. Otherwise we are providing a service by testing every use case possible! All in all, you could be more constructive with your critique, that's all!!

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Sorry I've caused a bit of a stir too! I'll take the blame as I could have worded my question a bit better I thin!